# How to map clustering results to known groups?

Tags: clustering

I have a data set, which form 3 known groups. I performed k-means clustering algorithm on the data set, setting the number of clusters to be 3 as well. I end up with 3 groups by k-means.

Wishing to see how well k-means algorithm has worked, I am trying to benchmark these k-means groups against the known groups. **The problem is, I do not know the correspondence.** Maybe, group 1 by k-means corresponds to the real group 3 or 2.

My idea is quite brutal: test all $3!=6$ possible correspondences. See which correspondence gives me the "best results". The "best result" may be defined as the lowest false/postive (I am not sure about this point either)?

Is there a standard/better way of finding the correspondence which in turn allows me to do the evaluation of the clustering quality?

Comment: Your question is pretty much the same as [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/117998/3277) one. Check comments on it, please. The empirical correspondence is found by diagonalizing the frequency cross-table. If clustering supports the existent classification correspondence will come obvious; if not - no clear correspondence will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please **read a chapter on cluster evaluation**.

Since - usually - the number of clusters is much smaller than the data set size, the cost of comparing $O(k_1*k_2)$ clusters with each other is neglibile. (Also note, that in general you shouldn't assume that every clustering result as the same number of clusters $k$!)

However, assuming a 1:1 correspondence of clusters isn't a good idea. For example, one algorithm may have *merged* two clusters, and *split* another cluster. Then there are 1:2 and 2:1 correspondences instead!

The common approach to handlind this is known as **pair counting**, and used in **popular clustering evaluation measures** such as the Adjusted Rand Index (ARI).

Two things that seem to be badly supported so far:

- hierarchical clustering results (e.g. OPTICS results)
- noise and outliers (e.g. DBSCAN results)